# Docker Wordpress Container Exits after ~30 seconds

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker

I am new to using Docker, and am currently trying to create a Wordpress website locally using a Wordpress Docker container, and a MySQL database (Note: I am also new to MySQL). The MySQL database is not running in a container, but I would rather like to make my own local database on my machine.

When I try creating a Wordpress container using this command:

```
sudo docker run --name wordpress_local -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=localhost -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=test -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=password -d wordpress
```

The container runs for exactly 27 seconds, then exits.

I am not sure if this is because it cannot connect to my database or not, however, when I create Wordpress containers linked to a MySQL **container** I do not have this problem.
Steps to setting up my database:

- Installed MySQL server and client on my machine
- Created a user called test@localhost and gave it a password
- Granted all wordpress privileges to this user

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:

The log for the container looks as such:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in - on                  line 10

MySQL Connection Error: (2002) No such file or directory

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in - on   line 10

MySQL Connection Error: (2002) No such file or directory

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in - on line 10

MySQL Connection Error: (2002) No such file or directory

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in - on line 10

MySQL Connection Error: (2002) No such file or directory

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in - on line 10

MySQL Connection Error: (2002) No such file or directory

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in - on line 10

MySQL Connection Error: (2002) No such file or directory

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in - on line 10

MySQL Connection Error: (2002) No such file or directory

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in - on line 10

MySQL Connection Error: (2002) No such file or directory

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in - on line 10

MySQL Connection Error: (2002) No such file or directory

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in - on line 10
```

EDIT 2:

Running `sudo docker events --filter wordpress_local` produces:

```
2015-06-10T13:57:11.000000000Z e9000a3a085731d527f0e64a26f681126f5885f9ef0d4a845361d581ae2d111a: (from wordpress:latest) die
```

Comment: What does `docker logs wordpress_local` say?

Comment: Also, is there a particular reason you want MySQL in the same container? We'll just pretend we're in the same room, so I can say: This is America, do whatever you want, but it might be a good idea to keep your MySQL container separate from your WordPress container. I had trouble when combining them, and separating them into different containers is considered a best practice, and also gave me fewer problems when installing.

Comment: I have added the docker logs (still trying to figure out how to format it). Also, @L0j1k, I apologize if I was unclear. My database is to be completely separate from Docker--it is just on the same machine that Docker is installed on

Comment: can you show `docker events`

Comment: Sure @user2915097. Since I am new to MySQL, I just assumed my issue would be a simple error in my command used to create my wordpress instance (i.e. used the wrong username/hostname). Does my command look alright?

Comment: Yes, but it does not enlighten me a lot :-) Do you have a timeout of more or less 27 seconds somewhere, when you connect to Mysql?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, how can I test this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Docker offers two networking modes: bridge, and host.

The bridge networking mode is default, and when using this mode, MySQL must be listening for connections on the Docker host IP address (`172.17.42.1`). In other words, the `bind-address` in the MySQL config file must be set to: `172.17.42.1`

My solution was to use the host network mode by adding the `--net="host"` flag to my command. This allows me to connect to localhost from my containers, and allows my to keep `127.0.0.1` as my MySQL bind address. The correct command is shown below.

```
sudo docker run --name wordpress_local --net="host" -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=test -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=password -d wordpress
```

**EDIT:** It is good to note that this is not a very safe method, as it allows the container to access local network services. A better method would be to compromise database flexibility and have it bind to the Docker host, or to allow the Database to accept connections from all services, and use a Firewall to filter out unwanted access.